# Angular 2+ best way to get "form.valid" from another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a form in a pop-up,

My popup is inscription component and my form is formulaire-inscription component.

[image]

I want to access my form.valid variable in inscription.component.html from formulaire-inscription.component.

inscription.component.html :

```
<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="inscriptionModal" [clrModalClosable]="false" [clrModalSize]="'lg'">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <authentification-formulaire-inscription></authentification-formulaire-inscription>
  </div>    
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="closeModalInscription()"> Annuler </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="closeModalInscription()" disabled=[!form.valid]> S'inscrire </button>
  </div>    
</clr-modal>
```

My question is what is the best way to acess to this variable ?

Comment: If your form is in `formulaire-inscription component`, how can form.valid be in your `inscription` component? Can you paste the template for both the components? in your HTML and also the parent one if possible

Comment: @Vandesh That my question i want to use form.valid in inscription component and i dont know the best way to do it :). I have paste the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your form is public in the `authentification-formulaire-inscription` component, you can just use a template variable (`#auth` in the updated example below) on this component and then utilize it in your `[disabled]` check later on:

```
<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="inscriptionModal" [clrModalClosable]="false" [clrModalSize]="'lg'">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <authentification-formulaire-inscription #auth></authentification-formulaire-inscription>
  </div>    
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="closeModalInscription()"> Annuler </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="closeModalInscription()" disabled=[!auth.form.valid]> S'inscrire </button>
  </div>    
</clr-modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

You refer this link, https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction to understand two way interactions (*parent <--> child*).

Especially, the section, 'Parent listens for child event' which explains about EventEmitter. You will need to add to each event like onPasswordChanges(...), onAgeChanges(...),... on the child component.

You can receive the formValidBoolean from parent component. With state of formValidBoolean flag, you can let Angular enable\ disable the button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="closeModalInscription()" disabled=[!formValidBoolean]> S'inscrire </button>
```

Note: Do not expect the same object transferred from child to parent. So, I choose, 'formValidBoolean' as @output() variable.